# Pandas: Get unique items from a groupby into separate rows instead of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When using the `unique()` method on a Series you get a `numpy` array as a result, this also happens when doing it on a groupby. Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd
L0 = ['G','i','G','h','j','h','G','j']
L1 = ['A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":L0,"B":L1})
dg = df.groupby('B').A.unique()
```

Resulting in this:

```
Out[56]: 
B
A       [G, i]
B    [G, h, j]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

I want each unique element in its own row though:

```
   A
B   
A  G
A  i
B  G
B  h
B  j
```

I can achieve this by hand like this (I'm deliberately omitting any iteration over DataFrames and only use the underlying `numpy` arrays):

```
de = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"])
for i in range(dg.index.nunique()):
    ds = pd.Series(dg.values[i]).to_frame()
    ds.columns = ["A"]
    ds["B"] = dg.index.values[i]
    de = de.append(ds)
de = de.set_index('B')
```

But I'm wondering if there is a shorter (and fast) way that doesn't need loops, creating new Series or DataFrames, or messing around with the `numpy` arrays.

If not, I might propose it as a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `Series`:

```
dg = df.groupby('B').A
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()))
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .to_frame()
print (dg)
   A
B   
A  G
A  i
B  G
B  h
B  j
```

Another possible solution is [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['A','B']).set_index('B')
print (df)
   A
B   
A  G
A  i
B  G
B  h
B  j
```

Comment: Oh yeah, `drop_duplicates()`, sometimes you forget the easy solutions. Thanks for both possibilities.

Comment: Yes, I forget for it very often too. ;)